# Is there a way to AND all the bits of an integer in c and get back a simple 1 or 0?

Tags: c

is there a bitwise operation or logical operation that can be performed on all bits of an integer in C and returns either 1 or 0

Ex. an integer containing 0b10101010 would return 1, 0b00000000 would return 0.

Comment: ANDing all the bits in 0x10101010 would give you a 0. Do you mean ORing?

Comment: What are the criteria? Shall every nonzero input yield a 1? Or is it parity? Or what?

Comment: pretty simple. anding any 0's will give you a zero, so you basically just want `if (yourvar == 0) { it's all zeroes }`.

Comment: Title and question don't match.

Comment: And all bits as in 1&0&1&0... for your first example?

Answer (score 2):

The question as originally written is self-contradictory, asking about AND but using an example demonstrating OR.

The AND of all the bits in the number will be 0 for all values that contain any 0 bit, and 1 only for the specific value with all one bits.

That can be written as `(i==-1)` for any signed integer `i`. For unsigned integers, the test is probably better written as `((~i)==0)` or something similar with more type qualifications applied.

The OR of all the bits in the number will be 0 only for the special case of 0, and 1 for all nonzero cases. That can be written as `!!i` for any integer `i`.

This works because the `!` operator (like all logical operators in C) is specified to test for logical truth in the usual way and return only the values 0 or 1 as appropriate. So `!!` is a useful idiom for converting an arbitrary C expression into 1 if the expression is true or 0 if false.

(**Update:** reworded to avoid undefined behavior potentially caused by the expression `i+1` overflowing a signed integer. Moral: don't do bit-wise operations on signed integers unless you really enjoy the muck. I've left behind an additional bit of UB that never occurs in practice. Signed integers are not obligated to be two's complement, and so -1 might not actually be represented by a word with all bits set.)

Comment: +1 I like that, but it makes me have to think - so I prefer mine ;-).

Comment: The AND solution doesn't work for `INT_MAX` (`i+1` overflows, which has undefined behaviour).

Comment: Right, I keep forgetting that signed integers have almost no guarantees in the standard. In many architectures and implementations signed and unsigned are really just different points of view of the same underlying ALU and there is no overflow. The standard allows for overflow and guaranteeing not to hit that case is a pain. I'll reword the answer to evade UB.

Answer (score 2):

If you anded all the bits of a word only "all ones" would produce a result of 1.  In your example 0b10101010 would produce zero not one.

If instead you OR'ed all the bits, *any* non-zero value would result in 1.

So the following would be type-safe for any integer type without assuming two's-complement:

```
int i = somevalue;

int and_bits = ~i == 0 ;
int or_bits = i != 0 ;
```

or perhaps more intuitively:

```
int and_bits = i == ~0 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

suppose you have an `int i`

the value you seem to want would be

```
`i != 0`
```

which will 'OR' all bits.

and after MSN's answer, I stand corrected.  `i == -1`  will AND the bits, assuming two's complement

Comment: `!= 0` does not get you the effect of a "binary and" of all bits of an integer.

Comment: Although more ambiguous to the less savvy, pmg's solution is good. And for conditional expressions, the value alone is enough.

Comment: How do you know what the answer is when the question remains ambiguous?

Comment: isn't it (i == -1)  ?

All bits must be set eeha

Comment: @Sam: The title says AND, the example is an OR.  See my answer; I think it covers both options.

Comment: `i == -1` will AND the bits where two's complement representation is used.  `i != -1` yields NAND.

Answer (score 1):

AND all bits:

```
i==-1
```

OR all bits:

```
i!=0
```

Comment: Should that not be `i == -1`? And with the proviso that the machine -1 is represented as two's complement?

Comment: @Clifford, uhh.. yes it should.

Answer (score 0):

In the examples you've given, you could simply check if your variable is equal to 0. If there are any bits in the integer that are not 0, then the integer's value will be greater than 0. In practise:

```
if (i != 0) {
    //Some bits are 1.
} else {
    // All bits are 0
}
```

Or, since C casts integers to Booleans automatically:

```
if (i) {
    ...
```

If you really want to get a 0 or 1 value out of your comparison, you can take advantage of more automatic type-casting to turn a Boolean back into an integer:

```
int j = i != 0;
```